# unable to extract day and month from date using R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
test_df <- data.frame("subject_id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2), 
                      "date_1" = c("8/6/2009 11:54", "28/3/2009 19:54", "18/2/2009 1:54", "11/3/2009 2:54"))
```

I would like to extract the `month` and `day` from the `date_1` field. So, I tried the below

```
test_df %>% 
  mutate(date_1 = lubridate::dmy_hm(date_1),
         without_year = format(date_1, "%d/%m"))
```

However, this throws an error like as shown below

```
Error in format.default(date_1, "%d/%m") : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, the code as posted works with me.

Comment: WHat does `test_df %>%mutate(date_1 = lubridate::dmy_hm(date_1)) %>% pull(date_1) %>% class` return?

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas - It returns `[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`. Any idea on why does it throw error?

Comment: No, I can only suggest that you close R and restart a clean session. It many times works. Maybe there's a conflict with other loaded packages, in my session I have loaded lubridate and dplyr only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_df %>% 
  mutate(
    asDate=lubridate::dmy_hm(date_1), 
    justDayMonth=paste0(lubridate::day(asDate), "/", lubridate::month(asDate)
  )
)
  subject_id          date_1              asDate justDayMonth
1          1  8/6/2009 11:54 2009-06-08 11:54:00          8/6
2          1 28/3/2009 19:54 2009-03-28 19:54:00         28/3
3          1  18/2/2009 1:54 2009-02-18 01:54:00         18/2
4          2  11/3/2009 2:54 2009-03-11 02:54:00         11/3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. May I know why does `format` in my code didn't work?

Comment: Alas, I cannot reproduce the error.  Your code returns the same as mine, but with month and day both padded with "0"s.

Comment: In your code `asDate` is a variable name. Am I right? Is it okay to use `asDate` as a variable name?

Comment: Strictly, it's the name of a column in the `test_df` data frame.  You're concerned about conflict with the `as.Date` function, I guess?  That's a fair point, but there's no conflict.  Not least because of the `.` in the function name.  Generally, I wouldn't name columns in a way that might conflict with built-in or other functions, or otherwise potentially cause confusion.  But here, to help make the code self-commenting, I did.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was confused with `as.Date`. new to R and learning things. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, one quick question. when I do `ceiling_date(date_1, 'year') - 1`, I would like to see for ex: `2009-12-31` but instead it shows `2009-12-31 23:59:59 UTC`.  Any help on how can I get rid of the time component?

Comment: `lubridate::as_date()` would be one option.  It's all in the online doc.

Comment: can help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563903/use-of-mutate-in-summarise-function-using-r

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try with `dplyr` and `base R`:

```
test_df %>% mutate(date_1=as.Date(test_df$date_1,format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'),
                   daymonth=format(date_1,'%d/%m'))

  subject_id     date_1 daymonth
1          1 2009-06-08    08/06
2          1 2009-03-28    28/03
3          1 2009-02-18    18/02
4          2 2009-03-11    11/03
```

Answer (score 1):

using base-R

```
format( as.POSIXct(test_df$date_1, format= "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), "%d/%m")
[1] "08/06" "28/03" "18/02" "11/03"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. May I know why the `format` in my code didn't work